# ¿Hacer una tabla o realizar una consulta siempre que ingrese el usuario?

Tags: php, mysql

Supongamos que tenemos 2 columnas de miles de registros y necesitamos contarlos para luego mostrarle el total al usuario, la cuestión es ¿Debería recontarlos cada que visita la pagina o debería hacer una tabla especial que tenga el numero ya contado de todos los registros y que con un botón se refresque?

Gracias.

Comment: no creo que la cantidad de registros se vaya a mantener fija, dado lo cual no creo que una tabla extra para contener esa info sirva

Comment: Podrías crear una tabla extra si al momento de ingresar un nuevo registro a la tabla principal, logras ubicar ese dato en la segunda tabla e incrementarlo. De esta forma siempre tendrías la segunda tabla actualizada.